# How to check/uncheck a checkbox programmatically in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

How can I check/uncheck a checkbox programmatically.

```
<input type="checkbox" formControlName="checkedGender" [checked]="checkedGender" (change)="checkedGender = !checkedGender" disabled />
```

I have this below angular code but its not able to check/uncheck.

**Angular line of code for checking the checkbox:**

```
this.formGroup.controls['checkedGender'].setValue(true);
```

**Similarly Angular line of code for unchecking the checkbox**

```
this.formGroup.controls['checkedGender'].setValue(false);
```

but none of those are showing any effect on checkbox, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you should remove [checked] this is already done by the angular forms api. Otherwise you change the value with setValue(false) to uncheck it, but in your code you say (change)="checkedGender = !checkedGender". SetValue triggers a change as well, so you are redundant. Just keep formControlName and work with reactive forms in all means, or use the template and remove the formControlName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular forms api should handle the change for you. So it should not be necessary to assign something to [checked] or (change) because reactive forms are doing this.

So just write

```
<input type="checkbox" formControlName="checkedGender" disabled>
```

The state of this checkbox will be set by the forms api